# Opacity animation on a UserControl in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, storyboard

I have a WPF application with an animation on one of my views. The animation repeats indefinitely and is pretty simple - just three arrows that fade from 100% to 0% opacity using a storyboard.

I initially had each arrow as an image, but I redrew the image using vector graphics saved as XAML (Paths).

I replaced the image tags with the new UserControl, like so:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <control:Arrow x:Name="arrow1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
        <UserControl.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="arrow1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:1" BeginTime="0:0:0" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="arrow1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.6" BeginTime="0:0:1" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </UserControl.Triggers>
    </control:Arrow>
    <control:Arrow x:Name="arrow2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1">
        <control:Arrow.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="arrow2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:1" BeginTime="0:0:0.2" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="arrow2" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.4" BeginTime="0:0:1.2" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </control:Arrow.Triggers>
    </control:Arrow>
    <control:Arrow x:Name="arrow3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2">
        <control:Arrow.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="arrow3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:1" BeginTime="0:0:0.4" />
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="arrow3" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.2" BeginTime="0:0:1.4" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </control:Arrow.Triggers>
    </control:Arrow>
</Grid>
```

The animation worked before, but now it's not and I'm not sure why. I figured opacity worked the same for images and UserControls, but perhaps I'm missing something. I've already searched for a solution here and Google to no avail.

Here's the UserControl XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="KioskPractice.UIElements.Arrow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             >
    <Grid>
        <Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Name="svg4163" Width="645.99999" Height="146.19125">
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <Canvas.Resources/>
            <!--Unknown tag: sodipodi:namedview-->
            <!--Unknown tag: metadata-->
            <Canvas Name="layer1">
                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform X="-34.142857" Y="-73.552293"/>
                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path4150" Fill="{StaticResource AirlineChoiceBlue}" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="{StaticResource AirlineChoiceBlue}" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" StrokeStartLineCap="Flat" StrokeEndLineCap="Flat" Data="m 679.64285 74.222299 0 50.000001 -320 95 -324.999993 -95 0 -50.000001 324.999993 95.000001 z"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provided code works just by removing Storyboard.TargetName="arrow1" (arrow2 and arrow3) from the DoubleAnimation tags

Comment: Is there a reason the naming breaks the animation for a UserControl but not an Image?

Comment: I believe the answer is here:
[link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.storyboard.targetname(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of managing each instance, if it is supposed to pulse all of the time and it is not interacted with, move the storyboard to the user control.  Note: I had to use a different color, as yours was not included in your xaml.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication13.Arrow"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" >
    <UserControl.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="path4150" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="1" To="0" Duration="0:0:1" BeginTime="0:0:0" />
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="path4150" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" From="0" To="0" Duration="0:0:0.6" BeginTime="0:0:1" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </UserControl.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Name="svg4163" Width="645.99999" Height="146.19125">
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <Canvas.Resources/>
            <Canvas Name="layer1">
                <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform X="-34.142857" Y="-73.552293"/>
                </Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path4150" Fill="Blue" StrokeThickness="1" Stroke="Blue" StrokeLineJoin="Miter" StrokeStartLineCap="Flat" StrokeEndLineCap="Flat" Data="m 679.64285 74.222299 0 50.000001 -320 95 -324.999993 -95 0 -50.000001 324.999993 95.000001 z"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Then your usage just looks something like this:

```
<control:Arrow x:Name="arrow1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this tip, but I want the animation to be staggered for each arrow. If you look at the timing on the code you can see there is two tenths of seconds difference between each instance.